# One out two displays failed after power failure

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I am running 16.04 xenial.  I have two monitors, both Dell.  One goes to a Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller, the other to a VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] (rev a1) (according to lspci).  Both connect using DMI

After a power failure, the E3-1200 has gone into a strange failure mode.  The monitor display tool detects it. [image: both monitors are detected. In this picture, the 19" monitor is connected to the E3-1200] However, it doesn't display anything.  I don't think this is a hardware issue because when I reboot the machine, I see a display of a circle going around clockwise on the monitor connected to the E3-1200.  As the machine goes through the boot process, I can see the monitor go very dark, and then merely dark.  If I unplug the monitor from the graphics card, it detects the problem and has an on-screen display that says so.

I have tried rebooting.  I have tried changing the display manager from lightdm to gdm3 and back.  I have tried ubuntu mate, gnome with software rendering, cinnamon, and ubuntu's default environment.

I tried running xrandr and got an interesting result:

```
jeffs@jeff-desktop:~$ sudo xrandr | fgrep connect
[sudo] password for jeffs: 
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+40 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected
DP2 disconnected
DP3 disconnected
HDMI2 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 376mm x 301mm        
HDMI3 disconnected
HDMI4 disconnected
VGA2 disconnected
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
jeffs@jeff-desktop:~$
root@jeff-desktop:~# xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 2
0: +*DVI-I-1 1920/509x1080/286+0+40  DVI-I-1
1: +HDMI2 1280/376x1024/301+1920+0  HDMI2
root@jeff-desktop:~# xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
0: +*DVI-I-1 1920/509x1080/286+0+40  DVI-I-1
1: +HDMI2 1280/376x1024/301+1920+0  HDMI2
root@jeff-desktop:~#
```

The E3-1200 doesn't see the DVI connector or the monitor connected to the DVI connector. For some reason, it thinks it is on the HDMI connector.

I had updated the entire distribution this morning using apt-get update & apt-get upgrade.  When the power failure occurred and the system rebooted, that must have instigated the problem.  So I did some creative googling and found the installation procedure for the latest graphics drivers, from Intel.  I installed the latest drivers, there were a lot of them, and then rebooted, and I still have the same problem.

The monitors I have only have DVI connectors, so buying an HDMI cable is not an option.

Comment: I left the machine on overnight.  When I came back to it this afternoon, the screen saver was running on both monitors.  When I unlocked the session, the monitor on the E3-1200 went dark again.  This convinces me that the hardware is okay, that the problem is in the software/

Comment: I fixed the problem.  I rebooted the machine (again) but this time, I went into the BIOS settings.  The Video output of the IGM (Integrated Graphics Module) was set to Auto.  I changed it to DVI-I (Digital).  Then I cycled power, rebooted.  I logged in.  Under the menu is preferences and from there, I went to displays, and arranged them the way I wanted them re-arranged.  Then I logged out and logged back in again.  That didn't solve the problem.  So I rebooted, and that didn't resolve the problem.  So I cycled power, and that resolved the problem.